# Finding points around circles?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to make a single object (in programming) from 2 circles, but as i skipped some math classes, I am paying the price now. Here I want to find the x,y coordinates of ABCD points which I could connect with a line. The circles can be any size and maybe even overlapping each other.

I'm even struggling to form the actual problem or question. But I do know the x,y and r of both circles, if that helps. A bonus question could be, how to calculate the area of the formed object, but I think I could try to find that by my own first.

Maybe this [drawing](https://imgur.com/Ck3ZJB7)  helps to explain (imgur).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you are seeking to do is to find the coordinates of the points of tangency if a line is tangent to both circles given that you know the center and radius of each circle.

Comment: Yes, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. I just can't seem to find the relationship between the size and the distance of the circles.

Comment: You need to find a point on both circles where the slope are identical and that goes through a point from each circle. Those constraints will define the line. Can you figure either of those out?

Comment: I guess, those are the points what I'm trying to find. Just by trying to solve it visually, it looks like the angle of those points from circle centers are pretty much the same as the angle from (x1,y1) -> (x2,y2) + r2 + 90 degrees. If that makes any sense! At least it's close.

Comment: Like shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/ayAgUYl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic picture that you have to consider ; in particular, working with the (external) center of homothety is essential :

[image]

The basic relationship is

$$\frac{r_1}{h}=\frac{r_2}{d+h}=\sin \alpha$$

From the first equality, one gets :

$$h=\frac{dr_1}{r_2-r_1} \implies \sin \alpha = \frac{r_2-r_1}{d}$$

In this way, one has all elements for getting the coordinates of the different points.

For example, if $C_1=(x_1,0)$ :

$$P_1=(x_1+r_1 \cos(\alpha+90°),r_1 \sin(\alpha+90°))=(x_1-r_1 \sin \alpha,r_1 \cos \alpha)$$

Waiting for your reaction.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what i needed! I managed to create P1-P2 line perfectly, but the P3-P4 is just a bit off for some reason if y != 0. And both lines are off when x1 > x2. But I think I need to adjust the formula to fit all situations. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/NRaHw0u) the result so far. Thanks a lot, moving forward!